# Docker exits as soon as its run

Tags: mongodb, docker

I am not sure if this is the right platform but I have an issue I have been battling for sometime now and frankly its just driving me crazy and my efforts to google it have not been fruitful either. A mongodb docker exits soon as run, see screenshot:
[image: terminal]

and upon looking at the containers, i see this:
[image: terminal]

and `docker logs [container]` is just empty. Any assistance will be highly appreciated as am currently just don't have any other ideas on how to go about this.

`cat /etc/os-release` gives the following output:

```
AME="CentOS Stream"
VERSION="8"
ID="centos"
ID_LIKE="rhel fedora"
VERSION_ID="8"
PLATFORM_ID="platform:el8"
PRETTY_NAME="CentOS Stream 8"
ANSI_COLOR="0;31"
CPE_NAME="cpe:/o:centos:centos:8"
HOME_URL="https://centos.org/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugzilla.redhat.com/"
REDHAT_SUPPORT_PRODUCT="Red Hat Enterprise Linux 8"
REDHAT_SUPPORT_PRODUCT_VERSION="CentOS Stream"
```

And `docker version` gives the following:

```
Client: Docker Engine - Community
 Version:           20.10.7
 API version:       1.41
 Go version:        go1.13.15
 Git commit:        f0df350
 Built:             Wed Jun  2 11:56:24 2021
 OS/Arch:           linux/amd64
 Context:           default
 Experimental:      true

Server: Docker Engine - Community
 Engine:
  Version:          20.10.7
  API version:      1.41 (minimum version 1.12)
  Go version:       go1.13.15
  Git commit:       b0f5bc3
  Built:            Wed Jun  2 11:54:48 2021
  OS/Arch:          linux/amd64
  Experimental:     false
 containerd:
  Version:          1.4.6
  GitCommit:        d71fcd7d8303cbf684402823e425e9dd2e99285d
 runc:
  Version:          1.0.0-rc95
  GitCommit:        b9ee9c6314599f1b4a7f497e1f1f856fe433d3b7
 docker-init:
  Version:          0.19.0
  GitCommit:        de40ad0
```

Comment: @JechChua nothing, no logs are produced

Comment: Have you tried running in [detached mode](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#detached--d) as suggested on the mongo dockerhub page?
`docker run --name some-name -d mongo`

Comment: Yeah, I reread you post. I missed that part. Anyway, from your screenshot exit(132) the container was aborted probably because of illegal instruction or corrupt. Can you try with other mongo images? I'm just guessing here but can you also remove your image then pull again a new mongo image?

Comment: @tentative I tried running the exact command she/he did and it's working as expected on my end.

Comment: @JechChua yea, i deleted local one and pulled again, same issue appeared, do you know of any other mongo images you can suggest?

Comment: Can you try this? `docker pull circleci/mongo`

Comment: i also found this `centos/mongodb-36-centos7` before i saw your suggestion and seemed to run fine, let me give all this a shot

Comment: so the alternatives work great